# How many @media queries in CSS should I do these days when making a site?

Tags: css, media-queries

How many @media's should do in CSS when making a website these days?

I'm thinking one for iOS, then one for larger phones (Samsung), one for small tablets, one for regular tablets, and one for laptops/ desktops.

Is that overkill?

Also can I get away with just using min-width for all of them to cut down on writing things twice?

Comment: It should really depend on your content / design. The actual device is irrelevant. There are new devices / screen sizes being created all the time.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can get away with using just `min-width` or `max-width` media queries - this is pretty common practice.

This is kind of an opinion-based question and therefore not entirely in the scope of Stack Overflow but I'll bite anyway.

The less media queries the better IMO - the more fluid / naturally responsive your design is the less you have to worry about dealing with a huge mass of media queries.  Most of the sites I build have only one media query, which is essentially between mobile and tablet/desktop resolution: `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) { }` so the breakpoint is 768.

If you think that's too restrictive you can add one at 1024 or thereabouts for desktop resolution, so you have mobile/tablet/desktop rather than just mobile and tablet/desktop.  Generally speaking though if you are using fluid layout techniques you should already be designing the site in such a way that you can get away with just a single breakpoint a la Zurb Foundation.

This encourages best practices in responsive design, is easier to maintain and lifts you out of the rat race chasing every new device resolution - there are far too many devices out there to optimize for specific screen sizes so it's better to design a site that will work on all of them instead of having 100 million media queries for every imaginable display.